# Apache 2.2.15 with WSS proxy rules issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, websocket, chatbot, actioncable

Having a problem with **2.2.15 Apache using wws** (web socket) rules.

To get 2.2.15 Apache to support web socket, we followed this guide "http://notmyitblog.blogspot.ie/2014/03/websockets-support-for-apache-httpd.html" and have successfully created the module + added it to Apache.

At this point, Apache is throwing a 502 error when we try to access a page using this.

We are not sure where in the overall httpd.conf file this rule should go.

The aim is to configure a **chatbot** application that runs using **ruby-on-rails**.

Our application is split between an Application server running **ruby-on-rails** on **puma** (10.1.1.2) and this Apache server (10.1.1.1).

Our httpd.conf contains:

```
<VirtualHost 10.1.1.1:80>
Server Name hostname
ServerAlias www.our.url>

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/cable [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:UPGRADE} ^WebSocket$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:CONNECTION} ^Upgrade$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* wss://10.1.1.2:3000%{REQUEST_URI} [P,QSA,L]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule .* http://10.1.1.2:3000%{REQUEST_URI} [P,QSA,L]
RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto "https"

<Location /cable>
  Require all granted
  ProxyPassReverse wss://10.1.1.2:3000/cable
  ProxyPassReverseCookieDomain 10.1.1.2 www.our.url
</Location>

</VirtualHost>
```

Is this format correct? Are any other configuration changes needed for this to take effect?
Is there any sort of test that can be done at server level to verify that the ws is configured and working?